# custom select arrow - chrome vs internet explorer display issues

Tags: html, css

I used css to style my select arrow, and it's displaying how I want it to in chrome. However, in internet explorer, it is displaying both the default arrow AND my restyled arrow. I'm fine with displaying either one in internet explorer, but not both. Any idea how to keep it as is in chrome, but change it to one or the other in internet explorer?

Here's my css:

```
select{
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat 100% 50%;

            -moz-appearance: none;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
            appearance: none;
            outline-width: 0;
            }
```

This is how it looks in chrome:

[image: This is how it displays in chrome]

This is how it looks in internet explorer:

[image: This is how it displays in internet explorer]

Update, using schylake's fix below - default arrow has disappeared, but would like the custom arrow moved to the right:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this is a very bad idea to do this as changing browser default items may avoid normal navigation. For your issue, you can do a specific stylesheet for IE using <!--[if IE 9]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance is not supported in IE. refer to this for more information about it.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp

The reason it works in chrome is because of this line

```
-webkit-appearance
```

This will work on IE10+. Found this while researching the same issue

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any recommendations for allowing it to display the default in IE, while keeping my custom arrow in chrome?

Comment: Which IE are you running i know a fix that works on IE 10+. I edited my answer the css code above will remove the arrow completely

Comment: Tried your fix above, and it got rid of the default nicely, but the custom arrow is still floating in the middle, rather than on the right. (And in answer to your question: I'd ideally like it to work in ie8+")

Comment: hmmm for ie 8 I don't think its possible to remove the arrow. What you can do is make a div and place it over the arrow with the arrow image you want. and make it so the div is shown above it but it clicks the bottom div. use this link to see how this is done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help; It looks like your original fix works in ie8+ (at least, it appears to when I emulate those browsers). Still working on bumping the custom arrow to the right though.

Comment: glad i could help :) ill see if i can find anything about moving the arrow

Comment: how are you adding the arrow to the select can you post the css?

Comment: yeah. the css is in my original post at the top

Comment: ok try adding 'right' after the repeat in the url line tell me if that works.

Comment: Adding "right" caused the arrows to disappear completely from the input.

Comment: with the right still there add this line to your css background-position-x: 244px; and make the px value 20 lower than your box value

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "make the px value 20 lower than your box value"

Comment: if your select width is 300 make the width for background-position-x: 280px;

Comment: still just makes it disappear completely =/ Having "right" in there gives me the yellow yield sign in dev tools and crosses out the url completely. Tried various background-position-x px sizes without the "right", and it has no effect

Comment: the last thing i can think of is using this http://jsfiddle.net/qhCsJ/4120/ this person made a custom arrow maybe this will help.

Comment: You rock! I took that jsfiddle code and swapped out their URL with mine...The fixed the issue.